# VGGNet fine-tuning: image size, time and epoch

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am new in deep learning, I would like to have some clarification to understand the deep learning.

I want to train my CNN model using VGGNet, should I use the same image size of VGGNet **224x224** input images for fine-tuning?

How can I determine the number of **epoch**?

How would it takes to train the model if the number of images is around 5000 images and the GPU Nvidia gtx 1070?

Please help me to find answers. 
Thank you

Comment: None of these are programming questions, the number of epochs is decided experimentally, not a priory. How long it would take completely depends on hardware/framework/actual code.

Comment: Will it takes hours, days or weeks?

Comment: You should set the hyperparameters for your model as per VGGNet defaults ,as you are fine tuning the  model.
And i agree with @MatiasValdenegro on how much time it would take.

Answer (score 0):

IT

I consider number of epoch is how many times you loop through entire data. Actually number of epoch does not help you decide when or where the network will converge. It depends a lot on your algorithm and your data-themselves. So it is OK to ignore it.

Your most important target is to find the model which have the best accuracy. In my experience, just let the machine run for 20 epochs. Then draw the loss-accuracy graph and select the model.

For example, in the graph below. I often choose model which is saved from red-colored range. Which help me avoid over-fitting.
(The image is copied from internet)

Hope that help.

[image]

Comment: *"The image is copied from internet"* Then I suggest you to **[edit]** your post and add a link to the source of that image.